# Using negated set [^] and what? to negate substring in same line

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm writing a parser than converts `LaTeX` math in to python `eval()` compatible string.

I get to a point where I have a string that looks like this:

```
\sqrt{4m/s} - \frac{3v+10.5v}{20a-8a} +1/2
```

Notice the still mostly `LaTeX` syntax, as well as some arbitrary "unit" letters thrown in.
I then use the following Negated set, to replace everything except what is in the negated set.

```
    mathstr = re.sub('[^0-9*()/+\-.Q]','',mathstr)
```

How Can I include a substring "sqrt" so that it can work in a similar fashion, and preferably in the same regular expression?

Right now my work around is replacing '`\sqrt`' with '`Q`', doing the line of code above, and then setting '`Q`' to '`sqrt`' after, my full routine for going from the above syntax to `eval()` syntax is as follows:

```
    mathstr = mathstr.replace(" ","")
    if pwrRe.search(mathstr):
        mathstr = re.sub(pwrRe,'**',mathstr)
    if MultiplyRe.search(mathstr):
        mathstr = re.sub(MultiplyRe,'*',mathstr)
    if DivideRe.search(mathstr) or sqrtRe.search(mathstr):
        mathstr = re.sub('\\\\frac{','(',mathstr)
        mathstr = re.sub('\\\\sqrt{','\\\\sqrt(',mathstr)   
        mathstr = re.sub('}{',')/(',mathstr)
        mathstr = re.sub('}',')',mathstr)
    mathstr = re.sub('[/*+\-^][a-zA-Z]','',mathstr)
    mathstr = re.sub('\\\\sqrt','Q',mathstr)
    mathstr = re.sub('[^0-9*()/+\-.Q]','',mathstr)
    mathstr = re.sub(r'Q','sqrt',mathstr)
```

Which results in the `eval()` syntax'd:

```
sqrt(4)-(3+10.5)/(20-8)+1/2
```

But this is sloppy, and it would be useful in many areas if I could 'whitelist' characters and substrings in one line, blowing away all other characters that come up.

EDIT:

As I continue expanding my script this list will get longer but for now I want to match the following and discard everything else:

```
0123456789()/*+-^sqrt <-- only sqrt when it's a substring
```

Here are a few examples:

```
Before: sqrt(5s+2s)+(3s**2/9s)
After: sqrt(5+2)+(3**2/9)

Before: sqrt(4*(5+2)/(2))\$
After:  sqrt(4*(5+2)/(2))

Before: sqrt(4v/a)-(3v+10.5v)/(20a-8a)+1/2ohms
After:  sqrt(4)-(3+10.5)/(20-8)+1/2
```

There is some nuance to this beyond simply matching only those characters as well. In my first example you can see I have v/a, even though there is an '/' there, I remove that as well.

Comment: Can you give some additional example lines, and what you want to match for each?  It's not super clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jedwards I added a section at the bottom with examples. I think my key issue here though is mixing character set matches with substring matches in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "deleting" characters that *aren't* specified, what about "keeping" characters that *are* specified -- this is easy enough since you've already negated the group:

```
[0-9*()/+\-.Q]
```

Then you can add any alternative literals you want, e.g.:

```
[0-9*()/+\-.Q]|sqrt
```

In Python, this might look like, using `join` and [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
tests = [
    ('sqrt(5s+2s)+(3s**2/9s)', 'sqrt(5+2)+(3**2/9)'),
    ('sqrt(4*(5+2)/(2))\$', 'sqrt(4*(5+2)/(2))'),
    ('sqrt(4v/a)-(3v+10.5v)/(20a-8a)+1/2ohms)', 'sqrt(4)-(3+10.5)/(20-8)+1/2')
]

import re

for (before, expected) in tests:
    matches = re.findall(r"[0-9*()/+\-.Q]|sqrt", before)
    after = ''.join(matches)

    is_ok = (after == expected)
    print(after, is_ok, '' if is_ok else expected)
```

Output:

```
sqrt(5+2)+(3**2/9)               True 
sqrt(4*(5+2)/(2))                True 
sqrt(4/)-(3+10.5)/(20-8)+1/2)    False    sqrt(4)-(3+10.5)/(20-8)+1/2
```

(the last one doesn't match what you're expecting because of the first forward slash, but that's outside the scope of the question really.)

Comment: I should've looked in to the rest of the re.* functions. Also need to read up on what the r does. Thanks a bunch. Additionally the third case passes with mathstr = re.sub('[/*+\-^][a-zA-Z]','',mathstr), I *THINK* that would cover any cases where I have units like v/a or m/s

Comment: @codeNoob `r` specifies a ["raw" string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).